# Запуск Python http.server из определённой директории

Tags: python, python-3.x

Суть вопроса в следующем:

1. Есть директория с локальными веб-страницами **~/<%DIRECTORY_PATH%>**
2. Есть команда для запуска простейшего HTTP-сервера **python3 -m http.server PORT**

Чтобы иметь возможность обращаться с веб-страницам из п.1, я должен руками пройти путь из двух команд: сделать cd в нужную директорию и запустить там с амперсандом сервер.
У меня есть скрипт на Python, который должен работать за меня.
Как можно ГРАМОТНО запустить сервер из п.2 из необходимой мне директории из п.1? Пусть даже каким-либо subprocess.Popen
В данном вопросе меня смущают два момента:

1. Как запустить сервер **из нужного места**?
2. Возможно ли это сделать при помощи subprocess.Popen? И как тогда будет выглядеть код для запуска, раз уж и сервер, и сам скрипт, запускающий сервер, запускаются питоном. А для запуска сервера нужен ещё и флажок -m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
import http.server
import socketserver
import os

PORT = 8000
DIR = 'DIR_PATH'
ADDRESS = ''

os.chdir(DIR)
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

try:
    with socketserver.TCPServer((ADDRESS, PORT), Handler) as httpd:
        httpd.serve_forever()
finally:
    httpd.server_close()
```

Ответ был найден
Ну и этот скрипт запускается через Popen, после чего обращается уже через браузер по локалхосту + 8000 порту.